# Problem using richfaces to blind up and blind down

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Using JSP and RichFaces.  The search div should blind up when the "Run Search" button is clicked and the results div should blind down.

```
       <div id="paper">

        <f:view>
            <h:form>

                <div id="criteria">
                    <rich:panel header="Search">
                        <h:inputText value="#{Bean.name}" id="name">
                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Enter Name: " />
                        </h:inputText>

                        <a4j:commandButton value="Run Search" action="#{Bean.runSearch}"
                                           onclick="hideCrit({duration:0.8}); showResult({delay:1.5,duration:0.5});"
                                           reRender="searchresultstable">
                        </a4j:commandButton>
                    </rich:panel>
                </div> <!-- end criteria -->

                <rich:effect name="hideCrit" for="criteria" type="BlindUp" />
                <rich:effect name="showResult" for="results" type="BlindDown" />

                <div id="results" style="display: none;">
                    <a4j:commandButton
                        id="searchbttn" value="Back To Search"
                        onclick="hideResult({duration:0.8}); showCrit({delay:0.9,duration:0.5});"
                        reRender="searchresultstable" />

                    <rich:panel header="Results">
                        <rich:dataTable id="searchresultstable" value="#{Bean.results}" var="req"
                                        styleClass="dataTable" rowClasses="oddrow, evenrow">

                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <rich:columnGroup>
                                    <h:column>
                                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Name" />
                                    </h:column>
                                </rich:columnGroup>
                            </f:facet>

                            <rich:columnGroup>
                                <rich:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{req.name}" />
                                </rich:column>
                            </rich:columnGroup>
                        </rich:dataTable>
                    </rich:panel>
                </div> <!-- end results -->

                <rich:effect name="showCrit" for="criteria" type="BlindDown" />
                <rich:effect name="hideResult" for="results" type="BlindUp" />

            </h:form>
        </f:view>

    </div> <!-- end paper -->
```

I am running this on tomcat web server.

The Libraries included are:

- JSF 1.2
- JSTL 1.1
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- mysql-connector-java-3.1.1.jar
- richfaces-api-3.3.0.GA.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.3.0.GA.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.3.0.GA.jar

I am getting two errors.

This on load:

> element.dispatchEvent is not a function

and this when the "Run Search" button is clicked.

> element.makeClipping is not a function

**EDIT**  It seems that other rich components work such as , however, I have tried multiple  such as fade and they do not seem to work.

Thanks,

Comment: What does 'blind up/down' mean?

Comment: it is a rich effect.  the div will blind up/down similar to blinds on a window.

Comment: here are some examples http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/effect.jsf;jsessionid=9E92F34062C180D0E4B796D745242DAC?c=effect&tab=usage

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but this code works with Facelets, so you may have to look at how JSP handle all this.

Comment: @ckarmann thanks.  i think something is wrong with the project (not sure what).  however the project came from svn so i just can't start a new one.  I took the above code and it worked fine in a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a parameter in the context.xml file.

Original File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/project"/>
```

The antiJARLocking parameter was not something I recognized, so I removed it and everything works fine now.

New File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/project">
```

Thanks for the input everybody.